# JSON object is valid and populated, but has no methods and it's data cannot be accessed (react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

I am working with an API that returns a JSON object of the following format:

```
{
  "Home": {
    "Office": [
      { ... },
      { ... },
    ]
  }
}
```

- I retrieve the data from the API, which returns a result just like many other endpoints.
- I cannot access its properties - **object['Home'] is undefined**
- It has NO methods - `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(item => typeof obj[item] === 'function')` returns an empty array
- .keys(), .map(), .values() etc are all undefined

This is the only JSON object that has this issue - no matter how I alter it, this endpoint seems to be broken.

In the API, I build this object as follows:

```
    var map = {};
    result.forEach(device => {
        if (!map[device.facility]) map[device.facility] = {};
        if (!map[device.facility][device.room]) map[device.facility][device.room] = [];
        map[device.facility][device.room].push(device);
    });
```

The response *looks* valid

Also:

- The JSON object is valid
- JSON.stringify has no issues with it
- Even calling JSON.parse on the result of JSON.stringify gives the same broken object

So how can a valid json object have no methods and no accessible properties? I know I am missing something stupid here

Comment: JSON is a text format. It has by definition of the JSON standard no functions.

Comment: Did you parse the JSON?

Comment: Yes, with .json() after the fetch

Comment: fetch....json() returns a Promise, not your object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to use `Object.keys( x )` and not `x.keys()`

Answer (score -2):

You will have to parse the JSON you are getting as a response from the API.
Then you can get the value either by using **object.Home** or **object["Home"]**

reference - https://mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/